# Extend template with own functions

Tags: meteor, extend, overwrite

Is there a way to extend meteors core Template with own functions?

I want an easier default access to form field values, like [backbone marionette ui](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md#viewbinduielements)

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  "submit #form-signup": function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Your email is:" + this.ui.email);   // <<<<---- simple access 
  }
});

Template.myTemplate.ui({
  "email"   : "#input-email",
  "password": "#input-password" 
});
```

For that i need to extend Template[name] with an ui function.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve similar result with the second parameter of your event callback, which provides the template context:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  "submit #form-signup": function(e, t) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $(t.find('#input-email')).val();
    alert("Your email is: " + email);
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes i know that, but i want a definition of the fields for a better overview and plain simple way to access the vars without writing the jquery code every time. My next step is to extend it with some automatic validation, thats why i want the .ui fields.